# How to send parameters to Html.Kendo().Dialog()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, dialog, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to send a parameter to `Html.Kendo().Dialog()`:

```
var diff = Num1 = Num2;
var msg = "The amiunt of " + diff + " will be subtracted" 

@(Html.Kendo().Dialog()
    .Title("Update")
    .Content("<p>" + msg + <p>")
```

However, that construct does not allow this, saying that "msg" does not exist in the current content

How can I do that?

Updated version:

```
if ((Math.abs(newAmount) < Math.abs(Amount)) && newAmount != 0) {


    $("#dialog").kendoDialog({
        width: "400px",
        title: "Split Ticket Confirmation",
        closable: true,
        modal: true,
        content: "<div style='text-align: center'>" + msg + "</div>",
        actions: [
            {
                text: 'OK',
                action: function (e) {
                    $('.modal-content').html('');
                    $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
                    SaveData();
                },
                primary: true
            },
            {
                text: "CANCEL",
                action: function (e) {
                    $('.modal-content').html('');
                    $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
                    return false;
                },
                primary: true
            }
        ]
    }).data("kendoDialog").open();
}
else {
    SaveData();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Razor HTML C# syntax, you can achieve it without errors by doing this:

```
@{
     var msg = "The amiunt of " + diff + " will be subtracted";
}
```

Then just passing it regularly to the Content as you already did.

If you are using JavaScript and really want to use that dialog inside script tags then you can do this:

```
var dialog = $('#dialog'), undo = $("#undo");

undo.click(function () {
    dialog.data("kendoDialog").open();
    undo.fadeOut();
});

function onClose() {
    undo.fadeIn();
}
var diff = Num1 = Num2;
var msg = "The amiunt of " + diff + " will be subtracted";

dialog.kendoDialog({
    width: "400px",
    title: "Update",
    closable: false,
    modal: false,
    content: "<p>" + msg + "<p>",
    actions: [
        {
            text: "OK",
            action: function(e){
                // e.sender is a reference to the dialog widget object
                // OK action was clicked
                // Returning false will prevent the closing of the dialog
                return false;
            },
            primary: true
        },
        { text: 'Action 2' },
        { text: 'Action 3', primary: true }
    ],
    close: onClose
});
```

To add another action per request, to the Html.Kendo.Dialog() construct you can do the following:

```
@Html.Kendo.Dialog()
.Actions(actions =>
{
    actions.Add().Text("Ok").Action("onOkClick").Primary(true);
})
```

And inside your your script tag you create the JS method:

```
function onOkClick(e)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I handle "OK" or "Cancel" buttons events in that construct?

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dialog

You can use functions inside the array of actions. I will try to edit one of the actions for you.

Comment: I'm talking about the option where I use `Html.Kendo().Dialog()` construct, not the JavaScript one: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dialog. How would I call action when I click "OK" button and how would I handle "Cancel" button click event?

Comment: Oh sorry, give me a second, writing it out.

Comment: @gene Updated the answer.

Comment: I tried to use JavaScript version and when clicking on "Cancel", the dialog did not close, even though I had `return false`. I updated my question with your suggestion'

Comment: returning false will prevent the dialog from closing. It says on my comment on the answer.

Comment: Thank's. Was missing that one

Comment: This only works the first time you render the page. You cannot update the content of the message on the fly and re-open the dialog. Is there a method on the Kendo dialog box that allows the content to be updated?

Comment: What I am doing is writing a partial into the page on the event that opens the dialog (instead of opening the dialog directly). That way you can pass the partial a model with whatever data you need to pass:

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing is writing a partial into the page on the event that opens the dialog:

```html
function OpenDialog() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ItemSearch", "Invoice")',
            data: {
                PartNumber: dataItem.Id,
                AltPartNumber: 1,
                Description: 1,
                Application: 1
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#SearchDialogContainer").html(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("An error occurred.");
            }
        });
    }
    
<div id="SearchDialogContainer"></div>
```

And in the partial:

```html
@model ParameterModel

@(Html.Kendo().Dialog()
    .Name("SearchDialog")
    .Title("Choose An Item To Add")
    .Content("<div class='k-textbox k-space-right search-wrapper'><input id='employees-search' type='text'  placeholder='Search employees' value='@Model.Property'/></div>")
    .Width(400)
    .Modal(true)
    .Visible(false)
    .Actions(actions =>
    {
        actions.Add().Text("Add Item").Primary(true);
        actions.Add().Text("Cancel");
    })
)

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#SearchDialog').data("kendoDialog").open();
    });
</script>
```